# Unable to open debugger port

Tags: android, debugging, android-emulator

My `Android Emulator` freezes in `Waiting For Debugger` mode and my Application fails to run(i have HAXM installed). In my debug console write this message

```
W/ActivityThread: Application turbotec.mpas is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
```

and here is the whole picture of virtual device and error occurred:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing the Intellij IDEA (Android Studio) .idea directory which contains configuration information worked for me:

Exit Android Studio
Navigate to the project you are trying to debug
Backup any files inside .idea that you modified (if your project checks any of these into VCS)
Delete .idea directory
Open the project in Android Studio

This worked for me two months Back

Also Check any other process running in your computer on same port and kill it

Comment: thanks for your answer. if i restart my android emulator, it is going to work normally again but i want to know what's causing this to prevent from happening again.

Comment: I Guess some firewall Issues Let this to happen.. Cant find the real reason

Answer (score 1):

Tools > Android > Enable ADB Integration

Disable then enable. All's good

Comment: Goodway to restart ADB